# Removing parentheses from formula

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a formula that has redundant parentheses and I'm trying to clean it up a bit. This is the formula that I am using:

```
Sheets(strFName1).Range("Z" & i).FORMULA = "=(R" & i & ") - (W" & i & ") - (T" & i & ") * (G" & i & ") / 100 - (X" & i & ") - (Y" & i & ")"
```

This comes out to look like:

```
=(R10) - (W10) - (T10) * (G10) / 100 - (X10) - (Y10)
```

Is there any way to change the formula in the macro to look like:

```
=R10-W10-(T10*G10/100)-X10-Y10
```

I tried removing the parentheses in the original formula, but it still continues to include them when I run the macro.
Thanks guys!

Comment: The formula you show comes out exactly like the result you've said you want. There are zero redundant parens in the formula. The question you're asking makes no sense - you have exactly what you want, and what you want to remove isn't there in the first place. How can we help you?

Comment: Sorry I should'be written the original formula before I tried removing the parentheses. I did remove them in the formula that you saw earlier, but it still comes out to include all those parentheses. I am doing this for mostly aesthetic reasons and I'm trying to clean up the formula. Is that possible?

Comment: No, what you describe can't happen (unless the formula is being written from somewhere else). If you remove the parentheses there (for instance, remove the one between `=` and `R`), it doesn't magically come back. That formula is a string concatenation, and it doesn't just change randomly after you build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that you are saying patens are added when the formula is entered. Can't test this right now, but does the following work?

```
MyFormula = "=R" & i & "- W" & i & "- T" & i & "*G" & i & " / 100 - X" & i & "- Y" & i
Range("z"&i).FORMULA = MyFormula
```